# Why is Wolverine afraid of flying?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, the-wolverine

Wolverine has said he's "afraid" of swimming because he's vulnerable in the water and can drown, but why is he afraid of flying? Is it an unexplained phobia or is it explained in any comic? We all know why Indy's afraid of snakes.

Comment: Can you cite a reference to where he's said he is afraid of flying? I don't seem to recall him saying that. In fact I seem to remember him being a qualified pilot in a few different aircraft.

Comment: He's never explicitly stated so, but he's quite evidently uncomfortable and very on edge in X-Men Origins: Wolverine and The Wolverine. Which is weird cause I just remembered that he seemed quite alright in Charles' plane in X-Men: Days of Future Past... Up until Erik started crumpling the plane. But still there seems to be a pattern, maybe it's only in the movies and it's not canon, but that's why I was wondering.

Comment: “he seemed quite alright in Charles' plane in X-Men: Days of Future Past” — and the X-Jet in X-Men 1. Maybe he puts on a front when other X-Men are around.

Comment: Very likely. I do clearly remember him in Origins telling Gambit "Would you please keep an eye on the-" "-the what? Clouds?", after which he still seemed uneasy. And since there was no affiliation with the X-Men back then and it was just Gambit, maybe that's why he was showing he's a little bit chicken when it comes to flying lol

Comment: Earth is 70% covered in water.  Most of time when you fly, it's going to be over oceans.  Then there's the fact that, even if he's effectively invincible, it sill _hurts_... most people don't survive plane crashes, after all.  Maybe the impact from a crash would be enough to knock one of his bones out of position?  Or perhaps he actually did have to make a non-voluntary, un-assisted fall from an airplane... and of course survived.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Noice! Never thought of it that way. It might actually be linked to his "fear" of swimming which has been shown as canon in many comics before. And about that last thought of yours, he did jump out of a plane around the end of the Origins movie, but voluntarily. But I can only imagine without a parachute moving at those speeds how the water must've felt for him.

Comment: He trained as a paratrooper during WWII, but that was pre having his memories and personality messed with by the Weapon X program so it's possible he could have developed a phobia later.

Comment: Maybe he just has aviophobia and the writers never really explain why.  I know in X-2 he shows that he's pretty uncomfortable with flying.  In Origins he outright states it.  However, in X1, X3, DoFP, and The Wolverine, he seems to be perfectly comfortable flying.  I think it should simply be attributed to the fact that these movies are poorly written and have more continuity errors than the 6 Star Wars movies

Comment: He's secretly a child of Poseidon. Like Percy Jackson. Flying bad.

Comment: @DVK Percy Jackson reference ftw. Have an upvote!

Comment: It's worth noting that "fear of flying" isn't always a cerebral fear of something bad happening.  Some people's inner ears have trouble with various aspects of flight, similar to sea-sickness or the way dogs sometimes get sick in cars.  Wolverine may just be intensely *uncomfortable* on planes, and thus have a Pavlovian "fear" of them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no mention of this fear of flying in the comics, the film scripts, the film's novelisations or the various graphic novelisations. As far as Wolverine's evident fear of flying is concerned, it seems that that was **purely an invention of the actor Hugh Jackman.**

> The 45-year-old Hollywood star admits he even incorporated a fear into
>   his X-Men character Wolverine because he didn’t want to play someone
>   who isn’t capable of feeling scared.
>
> “**I put a fear of flying into Wolverine that wasn’t in the script. I
>   thought, ‘I can’t like somebody who isn’t scared of anything.’”**
>   <sub><sup>[Bang Showbiz](http://you.co.za/news/whats-wolverine-afraid-of-hugh-jackman-reveals-his-biggest-fear/)</sup></sub>

and

> **Wolverine is afraid of flying. Are you?**
>
> No, I love it. I never get scared. But **I came up with the idea that it
>   would be kind of interesting if Wolverine hated flying because it’s
>   unnatural for an animal to fly.**
>   <sub><sup>[Daily Mirror](http://www.mirror.co.uk/tv/tv-news/wolverine-hugh-jackman-reveals-logan-2089483)</sup></sub>

---

Interestingly Wolverine director James Mangold [specifically spoke](http://comicbook.com/blog/2013/11/19/the-wolverine-screening-qa-with-director-james-mangold/) to your suggestion that Wolverine's fear of flying could be related to his known (and canonical) fear of water but he seemed unaware that the fear of flying was actually Jackman's invention!

> **What about - Logan on the plane - he's so nervous. It occured to me when I was watching this the first time that if he falls into the
>   ocean that he will drown and come back drown and come back - is that
>   why he doesn't want to get on planes?**
>
> *I don't know. They told me--everyone who's really knowledgeable about Wolverine has always told me--he hates flying. And Hugh was like "I
>   hate flying"--I mean, as Wolverine. I love the idiosyncrasy of it -
>   that's the beauty of him, I think, the beauty of Wolverine. It does
>   separate him from the kind of Batman, indestructible because of my
>   gizmos or Superman indestructible because I'm indestructible.*

Comment: God I love me some Hugh Jackman!

Answer (score 0):

There were several references in the comic book series, he never specifically said why other than that flying was unnatural. As for water, he was in the water a lot in the original comic series.  The movies have several flaws when compared with the original comic series.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  This answer is quite vague and likely to get downvoted.  If you could provide specific instances of such references it would greatly improve your answer!